# Typescript: use specific extended interface to satisfy generic "extends" type argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's a small code example (side note: I'm running Typescript v3.8.3):

```js
interface IOptions<T> {
  arg: T;
}

interface IExtraOptions extends IOptions<number> {
  arg2: string;
}

type Func = <T, OptionsT extends IOptions<T>>(options: OptionsT) => T;

const f: Func = (options: IExtraOptions): number => {
  return options.arg2 === 'dev' ? 0 : options.arg;
};
```

I would expect this to work, because `IExtraOptions` extends `IOptions` and would thus satisfy the `OptionsT extends IOptions<T>` constraint, but I get:

> Type 'OptionsT' is not assignable to type 'IExtraOptions'.
>
> Property 'arg2' is missing in type 'IOptions' but required in type 'IExtraOptions'.ts(2322)

Removing the `OptionsT` argument altogether and just using `IOptions<T>` as the type argument for "options" gives the same error. Replacing "number" with a non-default type doesn't fix it either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a generic function, the generics type parameters of the function are for the caller to determine, not for the implementation to fix as some arbitrary types. For example given your example, this call would be valid `f<boolean, IOptions<boolean>>({ arg: true })` and the implementation you specified does not return an object to satisfy those  type parameters.

The conclusion is that if you have a generic function, generally nothing but a generic function will satisfy as the implementation (although using very loose types such as `any`, `never` or `unknown` might also work).

If you want to create specialized functions, don't use a generic function, use a generic type that happens to be a function:

```
type Func <T, OptionsT extends IOptions<T>> =(options: OptionsT) => T;

const f: Func<number, IExtraOptions> = (options ) => {
  return options.arg2 === 'dev' ? 0 : options.arg;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsQDOAPACoB8yA3gFDLJxQDmAXMiQNzUC+11oksRClQBRAB5gocLDnwFkECRBAATeRmx5CREAFcAtgCNoFGnQaMATKwKTQjTj2pgAnphQAxXSATJSAGmQZLQISBSVVdWC5UjIKAF4AClxNOVZowhIASmR4ig5eBDkwZBhWLx8dA2MoQNEJKQyCBORk1MJkHLyqWmQoCDBdKBBkFNlCADoLS1z4+OQAchUIADcF5AB+ZAAGZFYxkKmmR05qIA)

Also you can derive `T` from `TOptions` to simplify things a bit:

```
type Func <OptionsT extends IOptions<any>> =(options: OptionsT) => OptionsT['arg'];

const f: Func<IExtraOptions> = (options ) => {
  return options.arg2 === 'dev' ? 0 : options.arg;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsQDOAPACoB8yA3gFDLJxQDmAXMiQNzUC+11oksRClQBRAB5gocLDnwFkECRBAATeRmx5CREAFcAtgCNoFGnQaMATKwKTQjTj2pgAnphQAxXSATIiMrQISBSVVdQC5IjgQFzIKAF4AClxNOVYIwhIASmR4igyggG0AcgtigF1OagQ5MGQYVi8fIlEJKQKE5GTUwmQcvKpaZCgIMF0oEGQU2UIAOgtLXPj45GKVCAA3YuQAfmQABmRWacD5pkcqoA)

Comment: Thanks -- the distinction between generic type and generic function was what I needed. I appreciate the help.